# An item with the same key has already been added error on vendors/customers/baccount screen

Tags: acumatica

[image]

I'm having an error regarding this, it applies on all BAccount Related screens.

Comment: Are there customizations published? Does the behavior still occur after unpublishing all customizations?

Comment: could be numbering sequences? sometimes the numbering sequences are reset back to a number that would cause the same record to be inserted with a number that already exists in the database.